# Solr: Index csv file

Tags: csv, indexing, solr, schema, ioexception

I am trying to index the CSV file in Solr using command prompt but it gives the Not found error.

Here is the command:

```
E:\...\solr-6.1.0\example\exampledocs>java -Dtype=text/csv -Dc
=gettingstarted -jar post.jar E:\cross-over\dataset\dataset.csv
```

[image: Here is the error]

Do I need to define schema for the data set first or is this something else?

Kindly assist me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more google search, I found that the core name was missing. Navigate to the directory where post.jar is. Here is the command:

```
java -Dtype=text/csv -Dc=core_name -jar post.jar E:\path_to_csv_file.csv
```